# shmget is not working

Tags: c, process, cygwin, ipc, shared-memory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
int main() {
        int i=0;
        int shmid;
        int *mem=(int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
        key_t key;
        key=1234;
        pid_t pid;

        shmid=shmget(1234,sizeof(*mem), IPC_CREAT|0666);
        if(shmid==-1) {
             printf("shmget error\n");
             return -1;
        }
        mem=shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

        if(mem==(int*)-1) {
              printf("shmat error\n");
              return -1;
        }

        for(;i<10;i++) {
               *(mem+i)=0;
        }

        pid=fork();

        if(pid<0) {
               fprintf(stderr,"Fork Failed");
               printf("array : ");
        }
        else if (pid==0) {
               printf("producer is created.\n");
               printf("array : ");

               for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
                         printf("%d ", *(mem+i));
               }
               printf("\n");
               for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
                      *(mem+i)=i+1;
               }
         }
         else {
                wait(NULL);
                printf("consumer takes control of array.\n");
                printf("array : ");
               for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
                      printf("%d ", *(mem+i));
               }
               printf("\n");
               printf("consumer is done.\n");
               printf("array : ");
               for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
                            *(mem+i)=-1;
                            printf("%d ", *(mem+i));
               }
               printf("\ndone.");
        }
        free(mem);
       return 0;
}
```

Parent process and child process share an array. So I decide to share memory between these processes. However, shmget function is fail, that means if i run the program, print value is shmget error. I don't know what the problem is. I tried to static allocation of array, dynamic allocation of array, etc. What's the problem? I use Cygwin.

Comment: You *do* know that `sizeof(*mem)` gives the size of **one** `int`?

Comment: I felt that point is strange, so I changed my code shmget(key,100,IPC_CREAT|0666); instead. but still it has error message

Comment: This call `mem=shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);` leaks the memory allocate here: `int *mem=(int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));`.

Comment: Replace `printf("shmget error\n");` by `perror("shmget failed()");`, see the error which most likely is `EEXIST` and probably get enlightened that the SHM is a system wide resource. Use `ipcs` to list it and `ipcrm` to remove it via the command line.

Comment: Why does it make problem? And I changed my array only int *mem. also has problem

Comment: and i replace perror, and that send message : function not implemented

Comment: Oh, yes, I see: "Cygwin". So well...

Comment: Cygwin is problem? It doesn't  support share memory?

Comment: Which version of Cygwin are you using?

Comment: Why the Linux tag, BTW?

Comment: I'm using the newest version, that is..

Comment: it is just related with linux C right?

Comment: There is no thing as Linux C.

Comment: `shmget()` seems to fail due to this https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygserver.html not being available, running, installed.

Comment: Really? Is the Cygwin the progrma that can use linux terminal under window?

Comment: Cygwin provides a UNIX-like environment under Windows. Linux is just another UNIX-like OS. And C is just another programming language, having been implemented in many environments. It s is indeed couple to UNIX for historical reason. However the whole Windows Win32-API is a C API a well (mostly).

Comment: oops, anyway it's the problem of program. I really appreciate your help

Comment: if I replace *mem dynamic allcoation --> int *mem, you looks like this code has no problem?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

From [Cygwin's Implementation Notes](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/std-notes.html):

> The XSI IPC functions semctl, semget, semop, shmat, shmctl, shmdt, shmget, msgctl, msgget, msgrcv and msgsnd are only available when cygserver is running.

More on the Cygserver here: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygserver.html