# Is it possible to turn off this feature to allow different programs access the same block via memory address with C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand how memory address works. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 127, * p;
    p = &i;
    long j = 0;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)&i);
    scanf("%lx", &j);
    p = (int *)j;
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

I ran the code 2 times at the same time and got 2 running programs waiting input.

Assume program_1 gives `0x7ffd66359b78` while program_2 gives `0x7ffc8b0d7af8`.

If I enter `7ffd66359b78` for program_1 I get `127`.

If I enter `7ffc8b0d7af8` for program_1 I get

> signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)

which means the memory address I get in a program during its execution only works within this program for that execution, is my understanding correct?

I guess it's some kind of OS security feature. What's the name of it? Is it possible to turn off this feature to allow different programs access the same block via memory address?

Comment: These are virtual addresses, not physical ones. Each process has its own address space. If you need to share some memory space between two processes, read about shared memory

Comment: It sounds like undefined behavior. What makes you think `long` can hold an address on your system? Use `uintptr_t` instead of `long`.

Comment: The memory sharing among processes is system dependent. On unix, you could use [`shmget`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36958676/1212012), on Windows, you have other [options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16771282/1212012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which means the memory address I get in a program during its execution only works within this program for that execution, is my understanding correct?

Yes.

> I guess it's some kind of OS security feature. What's the name of it?

Most importantly, [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Basically, in a simplification, each process has a hidden number that is added to the address when accessing memory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit

> Is it possible to turn off this feature to allow different programs access the same block via memory address?

It's called [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) and also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Approaches .

Comment: This doesn't answer why they get a seg fault when they type in the address that the program has given them. More likely `long` is 4 bytes on their system and the program has completely random behavior.

Comment: @Lundin: If that were true, their first case, where they enter the address from the same program (If I enter `7ffd66359b78` for program_1 I get `127`), generally would not work.